# Get all translations from all resource files by culture

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dynamic amount of `resx` files. I need to find an elegant way to get all translations from all resource files by culture in the next format:

```
Dictionary<string, string> (key->$"{resourceName}.${translationKey}", value -> translation value)
```

I know I can use the next approach:

```
        ResourceSet resourceSet = MyResource.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
        {
            string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
            string resource = entry.Value.ToString();
        }
```

But it will take all translations from a single resource, but since I have a dynamic amount of resource files it is not too much suitable for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've end up with a next approach:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetAllResources(string culture){
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // let's point somehow to our assembly which contains all resource files
        var resourceAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(EnumsResource));
        var resourceTypes = resourceAssembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(e => e.Name.EndsWith("Resource"));
        // Culture
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
        foreach (var resourceType in resourceTypes)
        {
            var resourceManager = (ResourceManager)resourceType.GetProperty("ResourceManager").GetValue(null);
            var resourceName = resourceManager.BaseName.Split('.').Last();
            var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo, true, true);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
            {
                var resourceKey = $"{resourceName}.{entry.Key}".ToLower();
                var resource = entry.Value.ToString();
                if (!result.ContainsKey(resourceKey))
                {
                    result.Add(resourceKey, resource);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

Keep in mind that it is not the fastest approach, since it uses reflection. So consider using caching strategy.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
var resourceManager = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
var resourceSets = new Dictionary<CultureInfo,ResourceSet>();
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
foreach (var ci in cultures)
{
    var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(ci, true, false);
    if (resourceSet != null)
        resourceSets.Add(ci, resourceSet);
}
```

I have two resource files in the solution `Resources.resx` and `Resources.de-DE.resx`. The dictionary will contain the available cultureinfos as the key with the corresponding `ResourceSet`objects as value. The first `ResourceSet` has ?
`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (just another name for en-US) as the key.

Comment: It will not work, since I have 70+ separate resource files... For instance - Exceptions.resx, MyCool.resx, SomethingElse.resx

Comment: Ooh, okay :) that makes things interesting. So you want the output to contain all strings from all resource files, grouped by culture? or just the strings from all resources with the current culture?

Comment: Exactly. I've already invented my own bicycle, take a look at least it works. :)

Comment: You could use the namespace as well as some additional filters, since the `e.Name.EndsWith("Resource");` would require some kind of naming convention for the resource files. But that aside, it's basically what i would've suggested next :D

Comment: Yes, I am trying to force naming convention in my project, I will write a separate unit test that will evaluate continuously that all resource files have `Resource` post-fix. Since all of us have NCrunch, the `dirty-bastard` who is not following naming conventions will be notified just after compilation. About namespaces, I don't think it is required in that case, let that code be more generic.

Comment: And to prevent your next question - yes, I am architect-repressor. :)